# Problems toggling link text with JQ

Tags: jquery, toggle

I try to use this code for toggling text on the link:

```
var showText="<span>Open</span> &darr;";
var hideText="<span>Close</span> &uarr;";
$('h1').before('<a href="javascript:;" id="hc_toggle_close">' + showText + '</a>');
$('#hc_toggle_close').click(function () {
    $('#hc_toggle_close:contains("Open")').html(hideText);
    $('#hc_toggle_close:contains("Close")').html(showText);
});
```

But it does not work! As well as an usual if ... else construction. Could someone please point me what's wrong here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `toggle` helper function:

```
var showText="<span>Open</span> &darr;";
var hideText="<span>Close</span> &uarr;";
$('h1').before('<a href="javascript:;" id="hc_toggle_close">' + showText + '</a>');
$('#hc_toggle_close').toggle(
  function () {
    $('#hc_toggle_close').html(hideText);
  },
  function () {
    $('#hc_toggle_close').html(showText);
  }
);
```

From the documentation of `toggle`:

> Whenever a matched element is clicked,
>   the first specified function is fired,
>   when clicked again, the second is
>   fired. All subsequent clicks continue
>   to rotate through the two functions.